# Change value Array of Objects in mulesoft

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I am beginner for mulesoft I have output payload transform message as below but I have to replace inside promotions array **planChangeRequired** attribute value as **true** always, can some one help me how can we replace it.

### output Payload

```
{
  "content": {
    "data": {
      "sharedDataGroups": [
        {
          "empId": 100,
          "empName": "Ram"
        },
        {
          "empId": 200,
          "empName": "Santhosh"
        }
      ],
      "promotions": [
        {
          "id": "14400007",
          "discount": 10.0,
          "planChangeRequired": false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "meta-info": {
    "version": "V1",
    "timestamp": "2022-02-11T12:48:27.679"
  }
}
```

### Expected Result

```
{
  "info": {
    "sharedDataGroups": [
      {
        "empId": 100,
        "empName": "Ram"
      },
      {
        "empId": 200,
        "empName": "Santhosh"
      }
    ],
    "promotions": [
      {
        "id": "14400007",
        "discount": 10.0,
        "planChangeRequired": **true**
      }
    ]
  },
  "meta-info": {
    "version": "V1",
    "timestamp": "2022-02-11T12:48:27.679"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Update` function would fit here.

[Update function](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-values-functions-update)

Using `update` function, you dont need to map inside **promotions** array as this well change **ALL** the **planChangeRequired** to **true**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
import * from dw::util::Values
---
{
"info": payload.content.data update ["promotions", "planChangeRequired"]  with (true),
"meta-info":payload."meta-info"
}
```

Output

```
{
  "info": {
    "sharedDataGroups": [
      {
        "empId": 100,
        "empName": "Ram"
      },
      {
        "empId": 200,
        "empName": "Santhosh"
      }
    ],
    "promotions": [
      {
        "id": "14400007",
        "discount": 10.0,
        "planChangeRequired": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "meta-info": {
    "version": "V1",
    "timestamp": "2022-02-11T12:48:27.679"
  }
}
```

Assuming you want to change different **empName** then update along with `if-else` can work here.

If you want to update all empName then you can follow the first approach
DW for all field update

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
import * from dw::util::Values
---
{
"info": payload.content.data update ["promotions", "planChangeRequired"]  with (true) update ["sharedDataGroups", "empName"] with ((if (($)=="Ram")("Shyam")else "Krish")),
"meta-info":payload."meta-info"
}
```

Output

```
{
  "info": {
    "sharedDataGroups": [
      {
        "empId": 100,
        "empName": "Shyam"
      },
      {
        "empId": 200,
        "empName": "Krish"
      }
    ],
    "promotions": [
      {
        "id": "14400007",
        "discount": 10.0,
        "planChangeRequired": true
      },
      {
        "id": "14400007",
        "discount": 10.0,
        "planChangeRequired": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "meta-info": {
    "version": "V1",
    "timestamp": "2022-02-11T12:48:27.679"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ITs working good

Comment: IF i want to update multiple arrays attributes can we use update function?

Comment: I want to update sharedDataGroups array empname as well can we use update function()?

Comment: Do you want to update all empname or particular empname?? @Krish

Answer (score 1):

try the below code

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
payload update {
  case .info -> $ update {
    case promo at .promotions -> promo map ((item, index) -> item update {
        case .planChangeRequired -> "true"
      }
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Harsha Shivamurthy i updated my code can you please check update your answer please

Comment: payload.content.data update {
  case .info -> $ update {
    case promo at .promotions -> promo map ((item, index) -> item update {
        case .planChangeRequired -> "true"
      }
    )
  }
}

Comment: I tired above code but its not working